# Getting Variable does not exist: String in an apex method

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am getting the error `"Variable does not exist: String"` on the `nextOne()` method when calling `String.fromCharArray()`.  I'm not sure how I'm losing scope of String or it's static methods.

```apex
public with sharing class NextLetterGenerator {
    public List<String> InputArray;
    public Map<String, Integer>Letters;
    public Map<Integer, String>Numbers;

    public UserIdGenerator(String input) {
        InputArray = input.toUpperCase().split('');
        InputArray.remove(0);
        SetLetters();
        SetNumbers();
    }

    public void SetLetters() {
        Letters = new Map<String, Integer> {'A' => 1, 'B' => 2, 'C' => 3, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 5, 'F' => 6, 'G' => 7, 'H' => 8, 'I' => 9, 'J' => 10,
                                            'K' => 11, 'L' => 12, 'M' => 13, 'N' => 14, 'O' => 15, 'P' => 16, 'Q' => 17, 'R' => 18, 'S' => 19,
                                            'T' => 20, 'U' => 21, 'V' => 22, 'W' => 23, 'X' => 24, 'Y' => 25, 'Z' => 26
                                           };
    }

    public void SetNumbers() {
        Numbers = new Map<Integer, String> {1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'E'};
    }

    public String nextOne() {
        if (InputArray[InputArray.size() - 1] != 'Z') {
            Integer temp = Letters.get(InputArray[InputArray.size() - 1]);
            InputArray[InputArray.size() - 1] = Numbers.get(temp + 1);
        }
        return String.fromCharArray(InputArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this turns out to be an issue of a bad compiler error message.  What the issue was is that I wasn't using the correct signature for fromCharArray.  It required a List of integers and I'm passing a List of String.  In the long run I didn't want that method anyway.  What helped me come to this conclusion was calling `return System.String.fromCharArray(InputArray)` and it showed me that I may be using an incorrect signature for that method.  Hope this helps others debug their Apex code.

Answer (score 1):

Please look through the list of [String static methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_System_String_fromCharArray.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_System_String_fromCharArray.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp). You can find here that there is not such methods with signature `String.fromCharArray(List<String> charArray)` but exist the next one `String.fromCharArray(List<Integer> charArray)`/